# Is there a way to use a image map coordinates in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, imagemap

I want to use the coordinates of an image map but not the map itself. So my question is can I use the coordinates of an image map and detect if a user has scrolled over those coordinates using jquery?

EDIT:

I'm aiming for something like this: (not actually using an image map, just it's coords.)

Coords from the image map: `186,106,199,86,220,86,241,94,245,109`

```
$("img#test").hover(function(e) {
        if (e.pageX >= 186 && e.pageY >= 106 &&
            e.pageX >= 199 && e.pageY >= 86 &&
            e.pageX >= 220 && e.pageY >= 86 &&
            e.pageX >= 241 && e.pageY >= 94 &&
            e.pageX >= 245 && e.pageY >= 109)
            alert("wewt");
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add event listeners to the  tags, directly or using jQuery. For instance:

```
<map name="testmap" id="testmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="10,9,58,27" href="#" title="" alt="You are on a rectangle!">
    <area shape="circle" coords="104,18,14" href="#" title="" alt="You are on a circle!">
</map>
<img src="/img/image.png" style="width:136px;height:36px" usemap="#testmap" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#testmap area').mouseover(function()
    {
        alert($(this).attr("alt"));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why did you edit it? I don't see the need to use jQuery just to read the alt attribute!

Comment: good point, `this.alt` is more optimal than `$(this).attr("alt")`